# Setting up VSCode to include/exclude folders for C++ intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I often have a project with CMake to manage my build system. So you can imagine I would have a load of third-party headers, and my own headers within my install folder.

This is extremely troublesome when I have 2 copy of the same header: one in my install folder (old one) and the one I'm modifying right now (new one). When that happens, sometimes intellisense won't know which is the correct one and might think that my function signature is wrong (because it is looking at the older version).

Same problem when you trying to Ctrl + Left click into a class/function in order to quickly navigate to its definition. It might direct me to the wrong file (in install folder) and thus modify that file won't have an effect in the project (since the "real" file will quickly modify the old one).

An example of what my `include` folder structure in my install folder:

```
- boost
    |- fake_boost_header.h
- eigen
    |- not_reap_eigen_header.h
- abseil
    |- real_fake_abseil_header.h
- my_header.h
- my_other_header.h
```

I have tried the following solution, but seems like it is not working:

Have includePath in c_cpp_properties.json to be `install/include/<all_third_party_folder>`.

Any idea is welcome. I'm more than open to use third-party plugin...

Comment: My approach is to abandon cmake's "module installation" concept and to utilize workspace-based project organization.

Comment: @user7860670 can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm confused, VSCode should be using the include paths defined in your CMakeLists.txt, so why is it reading anything from your install folder?

Comment: @cmannett85 Ok, I did not realise VSCode takes in account of CMakeLists.txt. Do you mean VSCode is using it to compile or using it for intellisense? I'm talking about intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me your `install/include/<...>` solution does the *opposite* of what you want, in that it will guarantee VS Code finds the headers in your `install` folder first.  You probably want `include/**` so that it searches all subdirectories in your `include` folder, assuming that's where the headers are that need editing.

I'm not sure why you'd want VS Code to know about your install folder, as that's the output of your build / code generation process.  If you need versions of third-party code in your install folder, have your build process copy them in from somewhere in your source tree, so that you're not mixing (external) source code and generated code in the same directory.  That is, treat the third party code as source code in itself, even if the only thing you do with it is copy it into your `install` folder.  Then you can add the `install` folder to the list of excluded folders in `.vscode/settings.json` to avoid VS Code searching those directories:

```
{
    ...
    "C_Cpp.files.exclude": {
        "install/**": true,
        ...
    },
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "install/**": true,
        ...
    },
    "search.exclude": {
        "install/**": true,
        ...
    },
    "files.exclude": {
        "install/**": true,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```